# Problem extracting content from text files using Python

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I am trying to capture the data [here](https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/c821gj76b/6w924d00c/9z903130m/AgriPric-07-30-2010.txt) in the second table (Field crops) titled "Prices Received, United States,July 2010, with Comparisons". I am using Panda dataframes to capture the table from the text file and then I will output it to a CSV file.

My code is as follows

```py
def find_no_line_start_table(table_title,splited_data):
    found_no_lines = []
    for index, line in enumerate(splited_data):
        if table_title in line:
            found_no_lines.append(index)

    return found_no_lines

def get_start_data_table(table_start, splited_data):
    for index, row in enumerate(splited_data[table_start:]):
        if 'Dollars' in row:
            return table_start + index

def get_end_table(start_table_data, splited_data ):
    for index, row in enumerate(splited_data[start_table_data:]):
            if END_TABLE_LINE in row:
                return start_table_data + index

def row(l):
    l = l.split()
    number_columns = 6
    if len(l) >= number_columns: 
        data_row = [''] * number_columns
        first_column_done = False

        index = 0
        for w in l:
            if not first_column_done:
                data_row[0] = ' '.join([data_row[0], w])
                if ':' in w:
                        first_column_done = True
            else:
                index += 1
                data_row[index] = w

        return data_row

def take_table(txt_data):
    comodity = []
    q = []
    w = []
    e = []
    t = []
    p = []

    for r in table:
        data_row = row(r)
        if data_row:
            col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5, col_6 = data_row
            comodity.append(col_1)
            q.append(col_2)
            w.append(col_3)
            e.append(col_4)
            t.append(col_5)
            p.append(col_6)

    table_data = {'comodity': comodity, 'q': q,
                  'w': w, 'e': e, 't': t}
    return table_data
```

And, then I am doing this:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
txt_data = requests.get("https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/c821gj76b/6w924d00c/9z903130m/AgriPric-07-30-2010.txt").text
splited_data = txt_data.split('\n')
table_title = 'Prices Received, United States'
END_TABLE_LINE = '-------------------------------------------'
_, table_start,_ = find_no_line_start_table(table_title,splited_data)
start_line = get_start_data_table(table_start, splited_data)
end_line = get_end_table(start_line, splited_data)
table = splited_data[start_line : end_line]
dict_table = take_table(txt_data)
pd.DataFrame(dict_table)
c = pd.DataFrame(dict_table)
```

```py
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

However, I am getting an error here. Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow please include the error you are getting to help us limit our search

Comment: pls, add the `error` u're getting. And minify your code as much as possible.

Comment: I have added the error.

Comment: If my answer helped u with your question, pls click the check mark next to it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### Cause of error:

`data_row` is a list of `6` elements.

```py
number_columns = 6
# ...
    data_row = [''] * number_columns  # [''] * 6
```

and `index` will increment with each iteration where `first_column_done = True`. But `first_column_done` will be `True` when `:` is encountered in a word, i.e

```py
if ':' in w:
    first_column_done = True
```

hence, for each iteration after `first_column_done` turns `True`, `index` will increment until it gets more than `6` which is the bound of list `data_row`.

```py
def row(l):
    l = l.split()
    number_columns = 6
    if len(l) >= number_columns: 
        data_row = [''] * number_columns
        first_column_done = False
        index = 0
        for w in l:
            if not first_column_done:
                data_row[0] = ' '.join([data_row[0], w])
                if ':' in w:
                    first_column_done = True
            else:
                index += 1
                data_row[index] = w    # error pos.
```

*In other words, U get this error for each line that contains a number of words greater than `6 - index` after the first occurence of `:` within a word in that line.*

---

#### Fix:

Use `split(':')` and `list comprehension` as well as python `tertiary operator`.

```py
def row(l):
    row = [ col.strip() for col in l.split(':') ]
    row[2:] = row[2].split()
    return [ row[i] if i < len(row) else '' for i in range(6) ]
```

Comment: I kind of understand what you are trying to say. Nut I am not sure how to correct for it. Can you help me out?

Comment: @alex can u state in words what u're trying to achieve in the above snippet, I mean the one that caused the error.

Comment: I am trying to extract the rows from the table and then feed them individually to the next function to extract the table in a panda dataframe